# CKEditor textarea not displaying

Tags: javascript, html, ckeditor

I'm currently testing the CKEditor wysiwyg, and it's loading fine when I call it, however within UI, the textarea it's self, where I type the text, is not showing up, there's no way to type in the area, basically it seems to be only showing CKEditor, nothing more.

This is the code I'm using to test:

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <textarea name="message"></textarea>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace('message');
</script>
```

And when I view it, this is how it displays:
[image: CKEditor]

Am I doing something wrong, or is it broken?

Comment: CKEditor version? Browser? Console output? It's hard to help without details.

Comment: CKEditor v4.0.1, Firefox v18.0, no console output

Comment: Perhaps you're missing a `wysiwygarea` plugin in your configuration.

Comment: Could you give the configuration you use? Or a link to an online demonstration? It is very hard to believe that this happens with a standard editor, standard config and without any console output.